# File generates line break only when included

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

This file below is working alone as `menu.php`, but when I include it in another file using

```
  <?php include("menu.php") ?>
```

it generates a line break. But why is that I don't understand, I tried several times, but not solved. So, please help me guys and girls.

```
<style>
/* Menu style starts*/
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    background: maroon;
    background: linear-gradient(top, maroon 0%, #800000 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, maroon 0%, #800000 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, maroon 0%,#800000 100%);
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #888888;
}
nav ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, black 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, black 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
/* Menu style ends*/
</style>

<div align="center" 
    style="height: 100px; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #0033CC;">
    <font size="12" style="z-index:; margin-bottom:0px;">
        Open Public Library
    </font>
    <br />
    <font size="4">
        It's still under process, coming soon with full facility
    </font>
</div>

<nav align=center>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">
                <!--img src="images/home_icon.png"/-->HOME
            </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="user.php">USER</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="guest.php">GUEST</a></li>
                        <li><a href="member.php">MEMBER</a></li>
                        <li><a href="admin.php">ADMINISTRATOR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="register.php">REGISTRATION</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="book.php">BOOK</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="book_content.php">INSERT</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">UPDATE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="show.php">SHOW</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SEARCH</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="feedback.php">GIVE FEEDBACK</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.php">SEE CONTACTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="register.php">REGISTER</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: what do you mean by line break? what is problmem with this?

Comment: Do you mean it's generating a `<br />` tag, or just a newline of whitespace?

Comment: David just a newline of whitespace

Comment: when I saw source of browser there is no </br> tag, but it generates a line break

Comment: Also, please be consistent in your use of styling information: if you wish to use `<style>`s shift the inline styles into the stylesheet if possible, and you probably don't need `<font>` either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using UTF-8 encoding, save file as **UTF-8 without BOM**

Comment: I guess, its most likely will be BOM :(